# Set chmod 777 on image upload

Tags: php, html, file-permissions

How can I set chmod 777 in this code? I'm having a problem in uploading my images to the server, can you help for this problem?

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$newfilename = time().end($temp).$_FILES["file"]["name"];

if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
    {


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `doctor-info` VALUES ('', '$licno', '$txtlname', '$fname', '$mname', '$address','$email' ,'$mobile', '$specialization','$twopecial','$threespecial','$fourspecial', '$newfilename')";
        mysql_query($sql);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/upload/" . $newfilename);

        echo "<script> alert('data save!'); </script>";
        $get_id =  mysql_insert_id();
        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `doctor-info` WHERE id='$get_id'");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
        $id = $row['id'];

        echo "<script> window.location = 'doctor.php?action=edit&id=$id'</script>";
    }
    else{

        echo "<script> alert('Not an images!'); </script>";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First set permission for uploading folder

```
if(!is_dir('/path/to/project/folder/images/upload/')){
     mkdir('/path/to/project/folder/images/upload/');
}
chmod('/path/to/project/folder/images/upload/',0777);
```

Then upload file

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/upload/" . $newfilename);
```

Your Image file will not need permission to render

Answer (score 0):

You can set the chmod of files using the following code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/upload/" . $newfilename);
chmod("/var/www/project/images/upload/" .  $newfilename) , 0777);  // specify the absolute path to file
```

Comment: I think you'd want to chmod the directory before moving the file.

Comment: what is the meaning of this /var/www/project/images/upload/?

Comment: @PPjyran..That is only an example. There you have to specify the absolute path to the image file.

Comment: yes i want to chmod the directory before moving the file to how can i do that.?

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to set the execute flag for images.
666 should be more than enough. Just set those permissions on the folder you are uploading to.